# In American English, is there more than one way of saying "pick up" a person when you call round to their home with a car to take them somewhere?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english

In Brit. English, I could say "collect" / "call for" / "fetch" / "pick up" "collect" the person. What would be the best way to say this in American English?

Comment: "To chauffeur someone" might be an option.

Comment: Yes. You can use "come get" or just "get" as in "I'll come get you at 8 PM."

Comment: Thank you. Would I say "I'll come and get her"? or no "and"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common expressions in American English, regarding arriving in a car to give someone a ride:

I'll pick you up at 8 p.m.

I'll come get you at 8 p.m.

I'll give you a ride at 8 p.m.

Some less common, but not extremely unusual, phrases:

"...come collect you at 8 p.m."

"...call for you at 8 p.m."

"...come by for you around 8 p.m."

"...stop over at 8 p.m."

"....be by at 8 p.m.

Comment: Yes, but collect is not much used in AmE.

Comment: It's possible to say "fetch" in AmE, too, though uncommon. Also, the last two ("stop over" and "be by") don't necessarily mean that the speaker is picking up the listener.